# Remove img from application cache

Tags: javascript, caching

my **index.html**

```
<html manifest="cache.appcache">

<img src="a.jpg"   width="300" height="100">
```

**cache.appcache**

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# v1.06

CACHE:
a.jpg
```

After loading the page load and show the desired image  a.jpg  . Then I delete img from directory . File **cache.appcache** has not been changed .Htn After loading the page load and show the desired image  a.jpg   ...Good.But then i add another picture with name a.jpg  and updating **cache.appcache**

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# v1.07

CACHE:
a.jpg
```

Why Download old picture ?